# DailyProgrammer 280 Easy: Counting on Fingers

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge, c++11

We are trying to count to 100 on two hands!

Input is given like so: LP  LR  LM  LI  LT  RT  RI  RM  RR  RP (i.e. 0111011100)

Where:

`L = Left, R = Right, P = Pinky, R = Ring Finger, M = Middle Finger, I = Index Finger, T = Thumb`

Our job is to make sure the code is valid according to [this counting scheme](http://www.wikihow.com/Count-to-99-on-Your-Fingers), and then show what the number represented is.

Original post can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4z04vj/20160822_challenge_280_easy_0_to_100_real_quick/?sort=top).

My solution validates the input by checking to see if there is a "1" followed by a "0" for the "left" hand, and vice-versa for the right. I have it set up so that positions 3,4, and 5 aren't checked (isn't necessary as they can't invalidate the input).

Looking for feedback on best practice, convention, better ways to solve problem, and really just anything :)

EDIT: I am not interested in checking for incorrect input such as "0123456789"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    bool isValid = true;
    int total = 0;
    std::string input = "0111011100"; // This one is 37 

    // Divide by 2 because there is two hands; subtract 1 to zero index
    int oneHandLength = (input.length() / 2) - 1;

    // Verify 
    for(int a = 0; a <= oneHandLength; ++a){

        // Left
        if(((input[a] - '0') > (input[a + 1] - '0')) && ((a + 1) < oneHandLength)){
            isValid = false; 
            break;
        }

        // Right
        if(((input[a + oneHandLength] - '0') < (input[(a + oneHandLength) + 1] - '0')) && (a + oneHandLength > oneHandLength + 1)){
            isValid = false; 
            break;
        }
    }

    // Count up the total
    if(isValid){

        for(int b = 0; b < input.length(); b++){
            if ((input[b] - '0')){
                if(b < oneHandLength) total += 10;
                else if(b == oneHandLength) total += 50;
                else if(b == oneHandLength + 1) total += 5;
                else total += 1; 
            }
        }

        std::cout << input << " is valid: " << total;
    }
    else std::cout << input << " isn't valid!";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "0111014321" is considered valid with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, your code is really good :) Good job.

The thing that bothers me is the inconsistent weird indentation, but that's probably because of copying and pasting.

1. The 2 verifying conditions do the same thing, you can put them together, which reduces maintenance in the long term, although for such a small project it's not really important.

   ```
   if (((input[a] - '0') > (input[a + 1] - '0') && (a + 1) < oneHandLength) ||
       ((input[a + oneHandLength] - '0') < (input[(a + oneHandLength) + 1] - '0') && a + oneHandLength > oneHandLength + 1));
   ```
2. Depending on the architecture, `int` is not guaranteed to cover the entire range of `std::size_t`, so you should use that as a type instead of `int` to avoid overflowing. This is not a problem now because you only have 10 fingers, but if you decide to add more... :)

   ```
   std::size_t oneHandLength = (input.length() / 2) - 1;
   //'auto' would also be possible if you want to
   ```
3. Don't use integers as booleans. It is better to clearly state that you want to check if the integer is greater than `0` (or equal to `1` in this case):

   ```
   if (input[b] - '0' == 1);
   ```
4. Although using parenthesis reduces confusion, I think you are using *too* many of them:

   ```
   if ((input[b] - '0')){
       ^              ^

   if(((input[a] - '0') > (input[a + 1] - '0')) && ((a + 1) < oneHandLength)){
      ^^              ^   ^                  ^^    ^^     ^                ^
   ```
5. You have inconsistent spacing, choose one and be consistent:

   ```
   for(int a = 0; a <= oneHandLength; ++a){
   int main () {
   if ((input[b] - '0')){
   if(isValid){
   ```
6. You aren't including a newline after the last output, which can be a "problem" when run in a shell:

   ```
   $ ./hands
   $ 0111011100 is valid: 37 $ (command here - on same line!)
   ```

Minor thing: You don't need to `return 0;`, so you can remove it if you want to.

Comment: Awesome! I noticed I tend to have an empty line after an if or for statement.  Is it fine or should I have the opening bracket be on that empty line?

Comment: @Poplop Doesn't matter, as long as you are *consistent* :)